# Problem with anonymous access removal

Tags: geoserver, authentication

I had my GeoSever server working properly and then I removed anonymous access but now I can't access even the login page anymore ...

Now it looks like:

`http://host:port/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.GeoServerLoginPage?Error=false`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

An error should appear asking for your credentials, instead the browser is trying too many requests.

Go to `/geoserver/ows?strict=true` and try to login there. Then go to `/geoserver/web/`.

If you can access the console now, reset an anonymous filter until a better solution is found.

If `/geoserver/ows?strict=true` do not work, you can try `/geoserver/rest` and then login and after access `/geoserver/web/`.